# What am I encrypting wrong here?

Tags: java, encryption, character

So I have a wordplay project to do and I have to encrypt some characters.  I am at the point where I am stuck, and when I run it and type 1 for encrypt it doesn't shift that many letters.  It just prints the work over again.  I am wondering what I could do to fix it where if I say "hello" it will print 1 character over and say "ifmmp"   Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordPlayTester{

    public static void main(String [] args){

    String word, reverse="";
    String original;
    int key= 0;
    String Menu= "1-Encrypt \n2-Decrypt \n3-Is Palindrome \n0-Quit \n-Select an option-";

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("-Type any word-");
          word = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(Menu);

       int choice=in.nextInt();
       if(choice==1)
       {
      System.out.println("Insert a Key number");
       int select= in.nextInt();


          for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++) {
             char c = word.charAt(i);
             if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
                c = (char)(c - 64);
                int n = c+1;
                n = n % 26;
                if (n < 0) {
                   n = n + 26;
                }
                c = (char)(n + 65);
             }
             System.out.println(c);
          }
          }


       else if(choice==3)
       {
       int length = word.length();
          for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
             reverse = reverse + word.charAt(i);
          if (word.equals(reverse))
             System.out.println("Your word is a palindrome.");
          else
             System.out.println("Your word is not a palindrome.");


          }
          else if(choice==0)
          {
          System.exit(0);
          }

         else 
          {
          System.out.println(Menu);
          }


  }
}
```

Comment: You subtract 64; you add 65.  Is that correct?

Comment: I believe that is what I thought was correct, is it wrong?

Comment: So Zong Zheng Li, you think that I should make them lower case rather than upper and it should run the word a character over?

Comment: You prompt for `select` but don't use it in the calculation, which is an oversight bug.  When I run it with input BYZANTIUMABELONE, the output is the characters DABCPVKWOCDGNQPG are printed one per line. Thus, you've achieved the effect of shifting by 2, even though you add 1.  The asymmetry between -64 and +65 does matter. Subtracting and adding 65 (aka `(int)'A'`) makes the code work OK on upper-case letters.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by prompt for select? And it will only work with uppercase?

Comment: Also, for future reference, it would be better to submit an  SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  In this case, your code would not ask which operation to do; it would only do encryption because that's all your question is about.   This reduces the code to be studied by those who would help you.

Comment: By 'prompt for `select`', I mean you output 'Insert a key number' and read an answer into `select`.  Your code will echo anything that is not upper-case unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some revised, simplified code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordPlayTester {

  public static void main(String [] args) {

    String word;
    int key= 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("-Type any word-");
    word = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Insert a Key number");
    int select = in.nextInt();

    for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++) {
      char c = word.charAt(i);
      if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        c = (char)(c - (int)'A');
        int n = c+select;
        n = n % 26;
        if (n < 0) {
          n = n + 26;
        }
        c = (char)(n + (int)'A');
      }
      System.out.print(c);
    }
    System.out.print('\n');
  }
}
```

Given an input BYZANTIUM and key 1, it outputs CZABOUJVN; given key 2, it outputs DABCPVKWO; given key 25, it outputs AXYZMSHTL; given key 26, it outputs BYZANTIUM.

Comment: Thank you, however when you type in lowercase it does not work, is there something that can fix that?

Comment: I took what you did, which only attempts to map upper-case ASCII letters, and made it work correctly for that.  You can obviously create a parallel block of code for lower-case letters, but it is pretty ugly. You can also simplify the code you've got. At the least, I'd expect to create a single function to do the two conversions (low, high, select and c as arguments). I expect Java has analogues to the C `isupper`/`islower` functions; use them. A Caesar cipher like this is not the epitome of security, of course. One variant is known as ROT13, corresponding to a key number of 13.